# include_bias in Polynomial Regression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm training a polynomial regression model after adding polynomial features with include_bias=True

```
X = 6 * np.random.rand(100, 1) - 3
y = 0.5 * X**2 + X + 2 + np.random.randn(100, 1)

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=True)

X_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(X)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X_poly, y)

print(lin_reg.intercept_, lin_reg.coef_)
```

[1.95551099] [[0.          1.07234332  0.5122747 ]]

Question: include_bias essentially adds another feature vector of 1s, for intercept parameter (theta0). so, Im expecting intercept 1.9555 in place of 0. Why does this return 0 for theta0? 
[[**0.**          1.07234332  0.5122747 ]]

Comment: What happens if you use `lin_reg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)`?

Comment: I'm getting intercept and coefficients as [1.95551099] [[1.07234332 0.5122747 ]]

Comment: Using `lin_reg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)`, I get `0.0 [[1.98961295 0.9598783  0.4996094 ]]`.